# Перестановки с фиксацией предыдущих элементов в Python

Tags: python, list, список

я столкнулся с такой проблемой:

> Нужно сделать ряд перестановок, на каждом шаге фиксируя предыдущий
>   элемент.

К примеру, если у нас есть список из 5и элементов(1,2,3,4,5) , то на первом шаге результат будет такой:

```
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

(1, 2, 3, 5, 4)

(1, 2, 4, 5, 3)

(1, 3, 4, 5, 2)

(2, 3, 4, 5, 1)
```

Мы получили 5 списков, теперь на каждом из них фиксируем последний элемент, т.е. в первом мы фиксируем 5, во втором 4, ..., в последнем 1 и переставляем на n-1 - ое место (т.е. 4 - ое) цифры по очереди слева направо, т.е. для списка (1, 2, 3, 4, **5**), 5 уже не учавствует в перестановках, но участвуют все цифры слева от нее, т.е.:

```
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

(1, 2, 4, 3, 5)

(1, 3, 4, 2, 5)

(2, 3, 4, 1, 5)
```

Затем переходим к списку (1, 2, 3, **4**, **5**), где 4 и 5 зафиксированы, и получаем:

```
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

(1, 3, 2, 4, 5)

(2, 3, 1, 4, 5)
```

Ну и так далее. Более детально Вы можете посмотреть в документе на [Google Docs](https://docs.google.com/open?id=1PwvuPKXPt3caY32c9soHXU1nTpEQaNWUvvTfWwFkDVh9QOQSrM3ZE1jg--s0) (с 7ой страницы).

К примеру, я написал код, который переставляет только лишь последний элемент:

```
exes = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
vertices0, templist = [], []
for i in xrange(len(exes)):
    templist = exes[:]
    tmp = templist[i]
    del templist[i]
    templist.append(tmp)
    vertices0.append(templist)
```

Comment: Почему-то мне кажется что результатом каждой перестановки будет список заканчивающийся зафиксированными элементами, перед которыми будет идти первый элемент списка, а все остальные в том же порядке сдвинутся на одну позицию влево. Т.е. пример исходного списка [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] фиксируем [6,7,8,9] результат [3,4,5,2,6,7,8,9]. Тогда задача просто решается, без перебора в цикле.

Comment: фиксируются числа с конца и до второго элемента. числа всегда будут натуральными, начинающимся с еденицы и до n. Фиксируются они по очереди, т.е. сначала n, затем список сдвигается вправо, ставится n-1, затем n-2 и т.д. потом фиксируются n,n-1 и тд

Comment: Не совсем понятна задача, если ошибаюсь поправите.
Задача получить список перестановок (список списков, как в цикле из примера) или только результат последовательности перестановок всех элементов (модифицированный начальный список)? Второе делается в одно действие простыми слайсами. l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], где 4 и 5 зафиксированы --> result = l[1:3]+l[0:1]+l[3:5] т.е. result равен (2, 3, 1, 4, 5) из примера. Вычислить позиции в слайсе несложно, зная длину списка и кол-во зафиксированных значений.